# Statistical Analysis Query: Assessing Odour Intensity Ratings with Concentration Levels in Odour A and B Groups

Tags: regression, correlation, dataset

I'm currently working on analyzing data from an odour rating task, and I have some questions regarding the statistics approach. In the experiment, participants were exposed to 6 different odour conditions and asked to rate the intensity on a scale from 1 to 7. The odours fall into two groups (Odour A and B), each with three concentration levels categorized as low, medium, and high. These concentration levels were established beforehand to ensure equal intensity between both conditions.

Now, I'm considering the use of regression, specifically with odour concentration as a predictor variable and intensity score as the response variable. I'm considering employing Spearman's correlation test to explore potential correlations between these variables. I chose Spearman's since none of the data resembles a normal distribution and because my predictor variable is an ordered group (low, med, high). Would it be appropriate to use this approach given the nature of my data?

Your insights and suggestions are much appreciated. Additionally, if there are any crucial details I might have missed, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the outcome is a rating, a good place to start is ordinal regression with *concentration* as a categorical predictor with two levels (also *condition* and *group*?). Since the same participant provided multiple ratings, participant can be a random effect. Not sure why you would need to compute correlations at all; you should be able to use the model to answer your statistical questions.